# How to flush Amazon Linux AMI DNS cache?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

The typical way of flushing the dns cache does not seem possible in Amazon Linux AMI:

- `service nscd restart` does not work because it's not included within the VM.
- `service dnsmasq restart` does not work because it too is not part of the VM.
- `service dns-clean restart` does not work because it's not part of the VM.

Amazon does use the old `/etc/init.d/networking` for network setup; would restarting this also flush the DNS cache?

Comment: What DNS cache?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no DNS cache unless you have installed and configured nscd or a caching name server.

Comment: I seem to have a somewhat related issue; there's no *DNS* cache, but something definitely seems to have cached the namesevers to use and I can't figure out how to force the server to realise that the nameservers have now changed...  Any ideas?

Answer (score 14):

This is because your EC2 instance uses amazon's dns server, which you can't refresh (e.g. 172.xxx.xxx.xxx). you just have to wait it out.

Comment: and if you really can't wait for it, a temporary workaround is to fake it by putting a DNS entry into the /etc/hosts file (but remember to delete it later!), assuming that it's one particular entry you're trying to refresh.